# redirecting domain.com to www.domain.com in Apache 2

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I heard search engines recognize domain.com and www.domain.com as different addresses.
So redirecting domain.com to www.domain.com would be better for SEO.

How would you do it?
I have access to apache.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put following lines in you .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you want this only for SEO purpose then you can also make www.domain.com your prefererred domain in Webmasters Tools.

In Google webmaster you can do
1.Goto https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/settings?
2. Under "site configurations > settings" you can set your preferred domain.

Answer (score 4):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Is there any difference between .conf and .htaccess? Thanks

Comment: .conf is the global, probably root owned config file of apache, while .htaccess is the user-controled config file for his/her vhost or www directory which overwrites the directives in .conf (if allowed, fine grained controls available).