# Redirecting domain.com/folder to www.domain.com/folder in Apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, apache2

OK using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055860/redirecting-domain-com-to-www-domain-com-in-apache-2) I'm able to redirect **domain.com** to **www.domain.com**. But i want to redirect **domain.com/folder** to **www.domain.com/folder** too. When I try **domain.com/folder** I'm getting redirected like this **www.domain.comfolder**. How to fix this?

My redirect configuration in .htaccsess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to test in a different browser or clear your browser cache.